# Python: Lookup value between two other columns in another dataframe

Tags: python, dataframe, type-conversion, between

I have a dataframe with IP addresses:

```
df_users.head(5)
    user_id ip_address
0   22058   7.327584e+08
1   333320  3.503114e+08
2   1359    2.621474e+09
3   150084  3.840542e+09
4   221365  4.155831e+08
```

I have a lookup dataframe where the ip_address as a low and a high, mapped to a country:

```
    df_ip.head(5)
    lower_bound_ip_address  upper_bound_ip_address  country
0   16777216.0  16777471    Australia
1   16777472.0  16777727    China
2   16777728.0  16778239    China
3   16778240.0  16779263    Australia
4   16779264.0  16781311    China
```

I would like to add 'country' into the above dataframe as a new column by looking up the ip_address between the lower and upper bound.

```
ip_data=df_fraud.ip_address.head(5)
k=[]
for i in range(len(ip_data)):
    ip=ip_data[i]
    tmp=df_ip[(df_ip['lower_bound_ip_address']<=ip) & (df_ip['upper_bound_ip_address']>=ip)]
    tmp=tmp['country'].tolist()
    k.append(tmp)
df_user['country']=k
```

However this returns:

```
user_id ip_address  country
0   22058   7.327584e+08    [Japan]
1   333320  3.503114e+08    [United States]
2   1359    2.621474e+09    [United States]
3   150084  3.840542e+09    []
4   221365  4.155831e+08    [United States]
```

The country column has those brackets in there. What am I doing wrong here?

Anyone have any idea what I am doing wrong? In SQL this is a very easy join with "between" as the operator. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***apply*** is my usual go to solution in cases like this:

```
def lookup_country(ip):

    return df_ip[(df_ip['lower_bound_ip_address']<ip) & (df_ip['upper_bound_ip_address']>=ip)]['country']

df_users['country'] = df_users.apply(lambda row: lookup_country(row['ip_address']), axis=1)
```

There is probably a join, merge or concatenation solution to this, but this is the more obvious way to solve the problem, I think.

Note: this solution relies on the conditions returning only a single entry.

Comment: Thanks Kamage. I made some changes and got a bit closer. For some reason there are these brackets in the country column. I am not sure why that is occuring.

Comment: That would be because you are converting tmp['country'] to a list and then appending that list to *k*. Instead of using *append*, try using *extend* so that the **contents** of the list get added to k, not the list itself.

Comment: Also, you have an equals sign on both sides of the condition. Perhaps it should only be on one side.

Comment: Good catch, you're the man thank you! The extend does not include the nulls for ones that it cannot find. Any thoughts?

Comment: oops, I mean this k.extend(tmp if tmp else ['NULL'])

Comment: Any reason you cant just implement the solution I posted?

Comment: The way I wrote it is how my brain works. I am stubborn and trying to learn iteratively. :) you are very helpful though and I appreciate your help quite a lot. Thank you.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/127076/discussion-between-trexion-kameha-and-karnage).

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I ended up using:

```
k=[]
for i in range(len(ip_data)):
    ip=ip_data[i]
    tmp=df_ip[(df_ip['lower_bound_ip_address']<=ip) & (df_ip['upper_bound_ip_address']>=ip)]['country'].tolist()
    k.extend(tmp if tmp else ['NULL'])
```